# DB server stalls due to excessive load of ecache requests while server startup

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, ehcache

I have medium sized and traffic ecommerce website. At a time around 200-300 visitors. Webapp features are:

1. Built in Java, Spring used for MVC
2. Using **Ehcache** to cache several data requests from database
3. Pure JDBC used for connecting to database (Using connection pool of tomcat)
4. Deployed on tomcat in an AWS EC2
5. Using RDS as a database server
6. Around 100 database connections assigned to webapp

I am using Ehcache extensively to cache most of the catalog data as it is requested by all traffic coming on website. But when I deploy a new version on tomcat, almost always database server gets stalled due to excessive queries fired. Ehcache does not able to help here because till now nothing is cached. Best case is that it takes around 45 minutes till when website remains extremely slow and ehcache manages to cache important data. Worst case is website gets crashed and application stops running.

On Development environment it works very smooth, as there is no traffic. To quickly find a way around this problem, we did a quick fix.

**The fix was:** In `ServletContextListener` we made a dummy hit to most crucial services related to catalog which was eating up the database server by excessive queries. Due to this change, as soon as application gets deployed we fetch all data related to catalog in our memory and ehcache caches it all. Thereafter, application becomes usable to public. Although, this change has caused around 30seconds of lag in start when we deploy the app but we managed to get away from 45 minutes of slow website.

This fix indeed solved our problem but it doesn't feel like a good solution. Because everything related to catalog or other crucial data is in memory whether it is going to get used to not. It is around 3.5 GB of data. Moreover, it is a nightmare now to work in development environment now. Because of low memory in development systems.

Please suggest a good way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling the cache at startup feels like a good idea. That's what I would do. If it fits in memory, I wouldn't mind loading too much stuff.

The alternative would be to have an expiry policy and to periodically ping the cache to remove expired entries. But it sounds more like a waste of time.

Distributed caching could also solve the problem but it means adding a layer of complexity to your architecture. I would do that only if necessary. And I don't think it is.

Then, to prevent loading in dev, just use a Spring profile that causes the loading to be active only in production (and staging ideally).

Comment: I agree distributed caching is going overboard at this stage. Thanks for telling about Spring profile, I was looking for something like this from a long time.